# Style select2 multi select same as single select?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

Basically what I want to do is have the *input* act as a display only, when clicking on the field I wish to have the dropdown with the search field the same as the single select.

The (badly done) mockup below explains this better than I can.

[image]

Does Select2 have this feature built in, or is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: it's kind of hard to figure out exactly what you are looking for. take a gander at the plugin Chosen, does that do what you want?

Comment: Select2 is based off of chosen, Have a look at the [demo page](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) see how the single select works? Now have a look at the multiselect, I like the whole "tagging" thing for the multi-select, but I don't want to type in the "tag input" I want a search field to appear below like it does in the single select version.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with Select2 loaded up if anyone wants to fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/yJYpY/ I think you'd have to hack up the S2 core to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still looking for a solution, have a look at my fiddle.

I have used a couple of fiddles posted about the question and combined it all into 1

Not perfect, but it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lkkm2L48/7/

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $.fn.select2.amd.require([
    'select2/selection/single',
    'select2/selection/placeholder',
    'select2/selection/allowClear',
    'select2/dropdown',
    'select2/dropdown/search',
    'select2/dropdown/attachBody',
    'select2/utils'
  ], function (SingleSelection, Placeholder, AllowClear, Dropdown, DropdownSearch, AttachBody, Utils) {

        var SelectionAdapter = Utils.Decorate(
      SingleSelection,
      Placeholder
    );

    SelectionAdapter = Utils.Decorate(
      SelectionAdapter,
      AllowClear
    );

    var DropdownAdapter = Utils.Decorate(
      Utils.Decorate(
        Dropdown,
        DropdownSearch
      ),
      AttachBody
    );

        var base_element = $('.select2-multiple2')
    $(base_element).select2({
        placeholder: 'Select multiple items',
      selectionAdapter: SelectionAdapter,
      dropdownAdapter: DropdownAdapter,
      allowClear: true,
      templateResult: function (data) {

        if (!data.id) { return data.text; }

        var $res = $('<div></div>');

        $res.text(data.text);
        $res.addClass('wrap');

        return $res;
      },
      templateSelection: function (data) {
        if (!data.id) { return data.text; }
        var selected = ($(base_element).val() || []).length;
        var total = $('option', $(base_element)).length;
        return "Selected " + selected + " of " + total;
      }
    })

  });

});
```

CSS:

```
.select2-results__option .wrap:before{
    font-family:fontAwesome;
    color:#999;
    content:"\f096";
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    padding-right: 10px;

}
.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] .wrap:before{
    content:"\f14a";
}
```